# I'm trying to compile alsa-driver-RTv5.18 but get date-time error for gcc 4.9.2

Tags: date, gcc, alsa, realtek

```
/home/user/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.c:1065:22: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   "Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
                  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

I've tried to

```
export CFLAGS="-Wno-error=date-time"
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to judge just by output of gcc, please add compiling invocation command line.
Generally, developers add -Werror gcc command line switch to prevent successful build when there are any warnings triggered during compiling, and "[-Werror=date-time]" is just a name of that triggered warning, not a switch you should find and change.

Try first disabling -Werror by removing it from CFLAGS or grepping it in your source directory recursively: `fgrep -lr -- -Werror .`, then removing it from each found file.